# How to Reverse Usb Tethering with VPN [tun0 interface] routing?

Tags: vpn, reverse-tether, iptables

I have a big problem and after many days I can't find any solution because I'm not Linux experienced user...

Problem: I'm using USB [Reverse] Tether (Windows share internet with android phone via USB cable) everything working ok (dns, HTTP browser, etc...)
BUT all VPN apps doesn't work! when I try to make VPN connection, it said "waiting for usable connection..." in notification and never be connect :(

I'm on 6.0.1, using Xposed with "Hack Connectivity Service" and "Fake WiFi Connection" modules and I'm sure need some rule in iptables.

[image]

How to route [only] VPN traffic throw [rndis0] interface?

How to route [another] app's traffic throw [tun0] interface?